# Use `tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad` to resize numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I want to use [`tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_image_with_crop_or_pad) on a Numpy array of shape `(100,100,2)` to get it cropped or padded to a target shape `(h,w,2)`.

However, when I do:

```
img = resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(img, target_height, target_width)
img = np.array(img)
```

`img.shape` evaluates to `()`, which is not what I expected. How do I turn the output of this function into a properly shaped numpy array?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing img = np.array(img)?
You need to define a session object and run or evaluate your variable right.
Otherwise, your first line would still be an op and because of that, your next line would not evaluate to anything

Answer (score 2):

```
img = resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(img_tensor, target_height, target_width)
with tf.Session as sess:
    img_output = sess.run(img)
```

Now `img_output` is a numpy array, but note that img has to be a `tf.Tensor` of shape `[1, height, width, channels]` so you might do this beforehand, suggesting your input image is already a numpy array:

```
img_input = np.expand_dims(img_input, 0)
img_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(img_input)
```

Comment: There is a typo in the session call (it should be: tf.Session(), with brackets)